# retrieve 5 last records from table by C#

Tags: c#, linq

I want to retrieve 5 last record of one of my tables in Data base by C# code.I don't want using query in Sql server. 
in my code I want to retrieve 5 last records in tt.what do I do? now it retrieves all of the Records

```
            var temp = db.Positions.Where(P => P.DeviceID == device.ID);
            List<Position> tempPositions = FilterPosition(temp.ToList<Position>());
            var tt = FilterStops(tempPositions, new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0), 100);
            List<JsonDevicePositionModel> returnPositions = (

                                          from p in tt

                                             select new 
                                                 JsonDevicePositionModel

                                             {
                                                 DeviceID = p.Position.DeviceID,
                                                 Latitude = p.Position.Latitude,
                                                 Longitude = p.Position.Longitude,
                                                 SerialNumber = p.Position.Device.SerialNumber,

                                                 Speed = p.Position.Speed,


                                             }).ToList(); 

            //    }
            return Json(returnPositions, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

If performance don't worry you, than just use extension method Take of Enumerable class:

```
var tt = FilterStops(tempPositions, new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0), 100).Take(5);
```

Comment: Doesn't Take return from the beginning?  I think he said he wanted the last 5 records.  You'd probably need to reverse ... I hope that's not a large dataset.

Answer (score 2):

You can try ...

```
from p in tt.GetRange(tt.Count - 6, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

an other possibility:
from p in tt.Skyp(tt.Count - 5).Take(5)

Comment: You don't actually have to do the take after the skip if you are wanting to go to the end of the Collection.

Answer (score 0):

```
var full = FilterStops(tempPositions, new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0), 100);
var tt= full.Skip(full.Count - 5);
```